# Unpredictable Python prints

Tags: python, python-3.x

Output for this sample code is unpredictable, but counter is correct.
It looks like bug to me and I didn't manage to find any explanation about such behaviour. rusText is not printable, but how does this fact affects other prints?

**UPD**: OS Windows 7, Python 3.5, tested with Sublime text 3

**UPD2**: In Python shell all seems fine so I guess it's a Sublime Text console output issue. Can anyone repeat that under Sublime?

```
counter = 0

def test():
    counter = 0
    for i in range(20):
        print('start')
        counter += 1
        rusText = 'текст'

        print(rusText)

        counter += 1
        print('\t\tend')
    print(counter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: with python 3.2.3 under linux, no unpredictable output... All is good. So, what is your unpredictable output?

Comment: maybe it is some problem with encoding in terminal/cmd.exe/etc.

Comment: Under win7 with Sublime 3 output I get random number of starts/ends and counter print may also not print. But Python shell itself print everything fine. So I guess it's Sublime text issue?

Comment: Can't recreate with Sublime 3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

I would use `import encoding-utf8` and `import encoding-1251`
Oh, actually you can also try changing the encoding from the ribbon menu

Comment: Could you elaborate? `import encoding-1251` will raise a SyntaxError, dash is disallowed for python name.